# Does adding NH3 to an HCl solution facilitate the dissolution of aluminum compounds?

Tags: solubility, equipment, boron-family

If we compare the two solutions hereafter, which one would better leach/dissolve aluminum metal/compounds present at/near the inner surface of the glass:

Solution A: $10\,\%\, \ce{HCl + H2O}$

Solution B: $10\,\%\,\ce{HCl + 1\% NH4OH + H2O}$

I'm asking because I'm looking for a solution to leach away aluminum (and other lesser trace metal ions) from the surface of borosilicate glass such that it won't contaminate puriss solutions in the glassware, and one suggestion was to use "salmi" (which I believe is $\ce{NH4Cl}$), so I'm now wondering if $\ce{NH3}$ in solution somehow facilitates the "grabbing" / solubility of aluminum in an $\ce{HCl}$ solution.

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: Include the primary goal and the question background to prevent wrong assumptions and requests for clarification. The otherwise proper answer to the provided question may not lead you closer toward reaching your goal, if it is not known to readers.

Comment: I would suggest to remove "/compounds" part leaving only aluminum metal: different compounds react differently, and an answer cannot cover them all. Also, I'm not sure solution B is a thing; at least, there is a charge missing on ammonium.

Comment: @andselisk: Thank you for you suggestions. I changed NH3 to NH4OH. I wrote compound because I must say I ignore what form(s) is taken by aluminum when part of borosilicate glassware and at the surface of it (maybe a mix of Aluminisilicates / Oxide(s) / Hydroxide?).

Comment: @Poutnik: The primary goal is to "leach away aluminum (and other lesser trace metal ions) from the surface of borosilicate glass such that it won't contaminate puriss solutions in the glassware". Is this enough? If not, please tell me what additional details would be crucial to include.

Comment: If you want to eliminate other metals than aluminum, you could use a solution of ammonia, because copper, nickel, zinc and other metals make soluble complexes with ammonia.

Comment: I guess the primary goal is: not to affect the composition of those solutions by the container material. What kind of puriss solutions ? Glassware may not be the preferred material at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aluminum metal is attacked by $\ce{HCl}$ solutions. But adding $\ce{NH3}$ or $\ce{NH4Cl}$ has no effect on aluminum reactions.
The same thing can be said for aluminum compounds. Adding ammonia or ammonium compounds is not recommended, because it does not help. Aluminum does not make complexes with ammonia or ammonium salts.

But I suspect this addition of ammonia or of ammonium compounds may have another effect. It may help dissolution of other metals if they are deposited on the glass together with aluminum, making complexes containing the metal and ammonia.

Comment: Thank you Maurice! So an HCl solution alone is enough to leach out any Aluminum from/near the surface of the glass? I've read online that HCl solutions dissolve aluminum but I don't understand why because I would expect an aqueous solution to turn AlCl3 into Al(OH)3 for which I found a solubility of ~2x 10^-8 g/100ml (20C).

Comment: Do you think an aqueous solution of NH4 + HCl would be better than HNO3 for some other impurities? And is it safe to assume a small amount if NH4 would NOT interfere much with the leaching of aluminum by HCl?

Comment: @Hans. First $\ce{NH4}$ does not exist. Only $\ce{NH3}$ and the ion $\ce{NH4^+}$ do exist. Second. using $\ce{HNO3}$ instead of $\ce{HCl}$ would depend of the nature of the impuritiy. Third I don't know what you mean with the question about the safety of adding ammonia.

Comment: @Hans. Concentrated $\ce{HCl}$ solutions dissolve $\ce{AlCl3}$ to form $\ce{HAlCl4}$, or the ion $\ce{AlCl4^-}$ . The hydroxide $\ce{Al(OH)3}$ is not formed in $\ce{HCl}$ solutions.